# how to create unsigned apk

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apk

I am using InteliJ IDEA for making my android project. I am wondering is it unsigned apk in out/production folder?

Another way is I try to create unsigned apk from project Structure/artifact ---> Android Application ---> From modul 'MyModule'. Then I set path where it should be located. After making a project it was created MyModule.apk but when I want to install this apk file in my device it said that 'Application not installed'.

Please could anyone tell me what should do in artifact for getting result. I assume that the resources not completely added in apk. 
I read docs in InteliJ Idea help but I couldn't get positive result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. Your apk needs to be signed in order for it to be installed, whether it's signed with a debug key or your main key. With Android Studio (which is based on IntelliJ), you just run the app, all the building, packaging, and the signing with debug key is done for you. And if you want to do the signing yourself, you can also do it from the command line, that's also possible, there are instructions for that on the android developer web site.

Comment: I have to sign apk with my own certificate. For that reason I need unsigned apk otherwise it can't be done.

Comment: Just tell Android Studio (or IntelliJ) where you store your certificate then it can just do the signing automatically for you.

Comment: It's complicated @StephanBranczyk I don't have directly access to this certificate. I have to just create unsigned apk and pass them and they going to be create signed apk.... I need unsigned apk.

Comment: As @StephanBranczyk said to install app it should be signed. You can't install probably because it is not signed. But this is what you want. I would also recommend to check logcat for exact problem with app installation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am going answer my own question. I found solution.

UPDATE: I couldn't install apk bcoz unsigned apk cannot be install. For installing you have to sign it with certificate (debug or release).

In out/production folder apk is signed with debug key, its not unsigned.

If someone has a problem creating unsigned apk. here is the answer.

**If you are using InteliJ IDEA or Android Studio.**

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-an-unsigned-release-apk.html

**If you are using eclipse use this**

To export an unsigned APK from Eclipse, right-click the project in the Package Explorer and select Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package. Then specify the file location for the unsigned APK. (Alternatively, open your AndroidManifest.xml file in Eclipse, select the Manifest tab, and click Export an unsigned APK.)

**With Ant**

If you are using Ant, you can enable release mode by using the release option with the ant command. For example, if you are running Ant from the directory containing your build.xml file, the command would look like this:

$ ant release

By default, the build script compiles the application APK without signing it. The output file in your project bin/ will be -unsigned.apk.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: link to jetbrains is no longer available. Seems like new link is https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-an-unsigned-release-apk.html

Answer (score 1):

Just make so:

- Remove block in app build.gradle:

  `signingConfigs { ... }`
- Set `signingConfig null` like this:

> ```
>  buildTypes {
>         debug {
>             debuggable true
>             signingConfig null
>         }
>         release {
>             debuggable false
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>             signingConfig null
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you unistall old application from device before installing new (MyModule.apk)?

To test and debug your application, the build tools sign your application with a special debug key that is created by the Android SDK build tools and your new application key isn't same in devices old app.

for building signed apk read this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

As @fish40 said, unsigned apk cannot be installed. In intellij 2020.2.3, the "generage signed apk" option is here:

[image]

I selected APK, clicked next. Didn't have a keystore setup so clicked "Create New" and created new keystore and used it to create signed apk.